# validating model in new dataset

Tags: r, coefficients

I have a dataset (d) in which I am looking at the prediction of hospital mortality (0 or 1) using tn1 and 3 other variables (rms package). I have built the model and now I would like to validate it in a second dataset using the same model coefficients. The variables have the same names etc, but I don’t know how to keep the coefficients from f1, rather than letting the model generate new coefficients for the second dataset.
I would be grateful for your expertise, many thanks, Annemarie

```
f1 <- lrm(outcomehosp ~ I(log2((tn1+0.001))) + apscore_ad + emsurg +
        corrapiidiag, data = d)

record_id|  corrapiidiag|   tn1 |emsurg|    apscore_ad  |outcomehosp  
7   3   0.27    1   24  1  
8   9   0   1   21  0  
9   7   0.11    0   22  0  
11  9   0   0   13  0  
12  9   13.9    0   17  0  
13  22  5.02    0   37  0  
21  9   9.6 0   34  0  
25  9   0   0   10  0  
27  9   0   0   33  1  
28  25  0   0   18  1  
30  9   0   0   19  0  
31  9   0.16    0   26  1  
32  9   0   0   13  1  
34  7   0   0   18  0  
35  9   0   0   20  0  
36  9   3.03    0   41  1  
37  9   0   0   18  0  
38  9   0   0   18  0  
39  9   0   0   17  0  
40  9   0.14    0   23  0  
41  9   0   0   10  0  
42  9   0   0   8   0  
43  9   2.45    0   11  0  
45  9   0   1   12  0  
46  9   0.16    1   17  0  
49  9   0   1   22  0  
50  9   0   0   15  0  
51  9   0.05    1   16  0
```

Comment: [predict](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.html)

Comment: `rms` models accept `coef` calls.

Comment: @42- could you possibly show me how I would do that, I've spent the last couple of hours searching in vain! Many thanks AM

Comment: @RobinGertenbach as in?     `predict(f1, newdata=dd)`

Comment: I usually avoid building answers to questions with no data.

Comment: @42- My apologies, I didn't think it would be helpful. I have updated my question with some sample data. Many thanks